# Likely late 80's, early 90's TV based sci-fi show taking place on a Colony Ship

Tags: story-identification, tv

From what I remember from the show, which, admittedly, is not a lot, however, from the aspects I do remember, they should be unique enough to sort out an answer.

The show was based around a group of colonists aboard a colony ship currently en route to their new home. If I remember correctly, the ship had many, many colonists aboard the ship; however, the show seemed to center around a particular ensemble of characters and focused on their lives, trials and tribulations as they hurtled through space.

As stated, I don't remember a lot, but, the one detail that I remember, quite vividly, is one of the characters who was playing the part of an engineer/mechanic. And, in pursuit of this occupation, he/she had elected to have part of their forearm surgically removed and a mechanical glove/appendage was then attached which had tools and unique, I don't want to say abilities, but, it had unique attributes that helped them do their job more effectively. Built-in tools and the like. The drive being that you had to contribute, in some way, to be able to be on the ship in the first place (although I freely admit that that might be my retcon and just might be me romanticizing their choice.) I also have a fleeting memory that other occupations had similar augmentations, but, I have no recollection of what they were, or if that memory is correct.

Lastly, the character playing the engineer/mechanic may have been a little person, or a young adult, but, again, a little vague in my memory on this one.

I don't remember the show lasting very long, likely one season, maybe two at most. Although I can't recall other episodes and/or features thereof, so, its run may have been even shorter.

That all being said, the one hardened fact from this question surrounds the choice of the engineer/mechanic to have part of their forearm removed and replaced with a mechanical 'glove' type attachment for occupational enrichment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a TV movie, not a series, but some of this seems to match [*Lifepod*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifepod) (1993) [(IMDb)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107415/) about a spaceship that explodes (it may have been sabotaged) and the 8 crew who escape in one of the escape pods.

One of them, Q-Three, played by little person [Ed Gale](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0301839/?ref_=tt_cl_t6), is an engineer who has an artificial left arm with multiple tools:

[image: Q-Three running with hand attachment]
[image: Q-Three switching attachments]

The entire movie can be viewed on YouTube:

Comment: Yes!  That's it.  Sorry for throwing you off a bit, haven't seen it for many, many years.  Well done.